# Shielding a signal with both GND and supply?

Tags: layout, shielding

What happens if a net is shielded by GND on one side and VCC on the other side inside an IC? Assume that the 3 lines are on the same metal layer.
This is an interview question and I would like to know if this actually serves any purpose or was just a googly question.

Comment: What is the "shielding" intending to do?

Comment: Shielding is done to isolate the analog signals from the digital signals in a common routing channel. But so far, I have shielded a bunch of signals with GND on either side or  VCC on either side but never mixed them for the same signal. Hence, the doubt.

Comment: OK, so was there more to the googly question that you haven't revealed in your question above. If you want this answered you need to drag context into the light else it's just a pointless question for soliciting opinions and that means it'll get closed down. BTW I know what shielding does but you still haven't answered what the context was behind the question. I mean "what happens" isn't directly answerable because it could attract responses like "well the weather outside is still the same" or "nothing happens until you reach a certain frequency" or "bad things happen above 100 MHz"...

Comment: @Andyaka, this was asked along with the need for shielding and methods of onchip sheilding, whether digital signals must be shielded or analog and why.

Comment: Do you see that the context is important. s it stands your question is just soliciting opinions because of the lack of context. You now need to focus your thoughts and ask a specific answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

Regions of metal will attract electric fields.

If the VDD and the Ground are not moving, there will be some (a lot, if this is wide metal) shielding.

For planar structures, the shielding by co_planar metals improves as the CUBE of the size of the un_moving regions.

Thus 10u + 1u + 10u, should be much much better shielding than 1u + 1u + 1u.

Howard Johnson awake me to this method, with his "Digital Black Magic" books of 20 years ago. Visit his website.

Also you can model this, as coupling between point charges as angles become flatter: there is an inverse_cubic relationship.